# How to get last few characters of varying length from a string ..?

Tags: java, android

I have a multiple string urls, from which i have to pick last few characters, which are id's infact. But the problem is that, the length of id's is not consistent, i.e., if one id is of length 6 then, other may be of length 5 or 4 and so on. The sample urls are like:

```
www.abc.com/xyz-123456
www.abc.com/pqr-5432
www.abc.com/lmn/opqr-25647
```

it could have been a lot easier if the length of the particular id portion would have been same, i could have used:

```
String abc = "www.abc.com/xyz-123456"; 
String id = abc.substring(abc.length()-6);
```

But now the scenario is different as length of id portion in the selected url is not the same always, How can i cater this varying id..???? please any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a [lastIndexOf](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) method on the String object that will let you find the position of the '-' (I take it that is your separator). From there you can do the substring.

Comment: @Pimastar, Thanks man, u have pulled me out of hell indeed...:P

Comment: Yes! Sure, i was trying but i am getting a message that i can accept answer in few minutes. So as the time passes, i'll accept that...:-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this.

```
String id=abc.subString(abc.lastIndexOf('\'),abc.length()-1);
```

Hope it will help you. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
String url1 = "www.abc.com/xyz-123456";
String[] url1Split = url1.split("-");
```

What you're looking for can be found in url1split[1]

Answer (score 0):

Use regex to remove all characters upto `-`.

```
String id = url.replaceAll("^.*-","");
```

or

```
String id = url.replaceAll("^.*-(\\w+)$","$1");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LastIndexOf or create the regular expression.